# Edit single item in database via textbox

Tags: c#, dataset

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 using (SqlConnection connection =  new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
{
 connection.Open();
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update dictionary set word=@word", connection);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", wordTextBox.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

I created a way to take a selected value in a listbox and add the item to a text box on a seperate form. There I am attempting to give the user a way to change that word and have it reflected in the dataset I created. Currently when I change that word it replaces every entry in my dataset with the new word as opposed to just the specific entry. I am trying to figure how to specify just to change that one item.

Comment: Well you need to specify which particular entry you're wanting to change using a "WHERE" clause (you should have a unique ID for each entry). All you're doing with your current SQL, as you said, is simply set each entry's Word column to whatever you have in your textbox.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are missing a `WHERE` clause in your query. You need to use a `WHERE` clause in your query to only update some selected records that you like :

eg : `update dictionary set word=@word WHERE ID=@ID`.

This is just an example. You have to put the WHERE clause as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I actually had something like that setup like word=@word where wordID=@wordID and it told me "must declare scaler variable @wordID"

Comment: WordID is the primary key in case that was confusing

Comment: You need to add it the same way that you have added @word, first in the query and then use a `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wordID", wordID);` statement to make sure it is passed rightfully.

Comment: Yeah it doesnt let me because WordID "does not exist in current context."

Comment: Somehow, you will have to manage to get that in or some other column to put in your `WHERE` clause to uniquely identify the records to update, else this will keep updating the entire table.